# Prove that $\lambda_{gh}=\lambda_h\lambda_g$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group; Consider the mapping of $G$ into itself, $\lambda_g$, defined for $g \in G$ by $\lambda_g(x)=gx$. Prove that $\lambda_{gh}=\lambda_h\lambda_g$.

This is question on page $74$ of I. N. Herstein.

If I look at  $\lambda_{gh}(x)=ghx=g(hx)=\lambda_g(\lambda_h(x))$. But this is not what the question says to prove. Is there something wrong with the question?? Or my approach??

Thank you!!

Comment: Why do you think that  this is not what the question wants you to prove?

Comment: The OP wonders why he can prove $\lambda_{gh}=\lambda_g\lambda_h$ when the task is to prove $\lambda_{gh}=\lambda_h\lambda_g$.

Comment: I think there's a little confusion with the notations, as $\lambda_h \lambda_g$ meaning $\lambda_g \circ \lambda_h$ (yeah, changing the order). That is, the operation between maps is the composition, not the group multiplication itself.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, oh, does Herstein compose on the right?

Comment: But @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez  i am getting $\lambda_{gh}=\lambda_g\lambda_h$ whereas I need to show $\lambda_{gh}=\lambda_h\lambda_g$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the problem statement from Herstein's *Topics in Algebra*, 2nd ed:

[image]

As you can see, Herstein defines function application *on the right* ($x\lambda_g$ means $(x)\lambda_g$) and so you get the reverse order of composition.

Your answer can be readily adapted to this convention:
$$(x)\lambda_{gh}=(gh)x=g(hx)=(hx)\lambda_g = ((x)\lambda_h)\lambda_g= (x)(\lambda_h\circ\lambda_g)$$

Comment: @Ihf.. How does it change things???

Comment: @TattwamasiAmrutam, see my edited answer.

Comment: @Ihf.. thankyou!!!

Answer (score 0):

In seeing $\lambda_g\lambda_h$ you may think that is a multiplication. But, ask yourself: where we are? What kind of multiplication is defined here?

$\lambda_g\in Aut(G)$ and $Aut(G)$ is a group wrt the composition, i.e. we are working in the group $(Aut(G),\circ)$.

Hence when we write $\lambda_g\lambda_h$ we mean exactly $\lambda_g\circ\lambda_h$! And this is exactly what you wrote in the end:

$\lambda_{gh}(x)=(gh)x=g(hx)=g\lambda_h(x)=\lambda_g(\lambda_h(x))=(\lambda_g\circ\lambda_h)(x)$. Since this holds $\forall x\in G$, we can conclude that $\lambda_{gh}=\lambda_g\circ\lambda_h$.

Comment: The OP has already shown this. His problem is that the book wants him to prove $\lambda_{gh} = \lambda_h\lambda_g$.

Comment: @Joe Dude this is what I have shown. What the question wants to show is that $\lambda_{gh}=\lambda_h\lambda_g$